# MySQL Query to find users still inside room

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Below is my database table, where I will have Check In and Check Out entry records for attending the conference room.

```
id  registration_id roomno day type
1   101             1      2   In
2   103             1      2   In
3   101             1      2   Out
4   105             1      2   In
5   103             1      2   Out
6   101             1      2   In
7   103             1      2   In
8   101             1      2   Out
9   105             1      2   In
10  103             1      2   Out
```

Now, I want to select those records, which are still attending the conference. Condition is like their last record should be `type = In`. There can be multiple In/Out entries for each user during a day.

Please let me know the quickest possible MySQL query.

Thanks

**Answer which I ended up using:**

```
select * from `registrations_inouts` t 
group by t.registration_id 
having max(id) = max(case when type = 'In' then id end) 
order by rand() limit 1;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one method using `not exists`:

```
select *
from t
where t.type = 'In' and
      not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.registration_id = t.registration_id and t2.type = 'Out'
                 );
```

Another method uses conditional aggregation:

```
select t.registration_id
from t
group by t.registration_id
having max(id) = max(case when type = 'In' then id end);
```

Note:  both of these assume that the ids are assigned sequentially in time, so larger ids are later in time.

Comment: This worked like a charm, thank you for quick response :)